# Is there any way to perform click actions on tableau Dashboard

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, tableau-api

I am trying to perform click, drag and drop actions on tableau dashboard. I am using selenium for navigation. I did not find anything on the web for this. Tableau UI contains the graph and charts which are populated using html5 canvas, so XPath is not available for these components.

Comment: It's not very easy. But you probably need to post some HTML or a link to the page you are trying to automate, in addition to the code that you are trying to use now.

Comment: If they use html overlays for certain things it'll be easier, but the canvas itself is just a bitmap so Selenium won't know much about it.  I think tableau uses WebAssembly to draw/redraw the bitmap and to set event handlers.   This means you have automate mouse events (using Selenium "actions") using specific pixel locations inside the canvas.   Also see: https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/automated-testing-of-html5-canvas/

Comment: Thanks Cristine and pcalkins. you approach is helpful.